# Can we have multiple FBA accounts having same email address?

Tags: sharepoint-server, email, active-directory, forms-authentication, ad

I have a scenario where I will be creating 2 or more FBA accounts having the same email address.

1. First place, is this scenario valid? Does SharePoint allow to create accounts with duplicate email addresses?
2. I was using SharePoint FBA pack earlier and I know that FBA pack will not allow the creation of users with a duplicate email address.
3. If this is possible, what are its impacts on the SharePoint Sites/Custom applications?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you can change that in your membership settings in your web.config.

requiresUniqueEmail="false"

https://forums.visigo.com/t/creating-multiple-fba-accounts-with-same-email-address/840cs